# How to write mathematical expressions in R markdown's Chunk?

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown

I was trying to put the markdown expression `$log_{4}{30}$` in the comment section `c` in the Chunk(which is `#(c)`), however it did not work, but it is fine to see the right output expression outside the chunk. How can I write mathematical expression in the R markdown comment section (# part)?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://www.calvin.edu/~rpruim/courses/m343/F12/RStudio/LatexExamples.html)?

Comment: You should clarify your question - *you want to write equation as R comment*, right?

Comment: I think you have to stick to [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations).